# Does the part of my string exist in another string?

Tags: asp-classic, postal-code

Sorry for this question, I'm quite rusty on my classic ASP and can't get my head around it.

I have a variable containing the start of a series of postcodes:

```
strPostCode = "HS1,HS2,HS3,HS4,HS5,HS6,HS7,HS8,HS9,IV41,IV42" etc etc
```

Now I need to see if the post code a user has entered exists in that string.

so, "HS2 4AB", "HS2", "HS24AB" all need to return a match.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to split the post codes by comma then go one by one and look for a match.

Code would look like this:

```vbs
Dim strPostCode, strInput, x
Dim arrPostCodes, curPostCode, blnFoundMatch
strPostCode = "HS1,HS2,HS3,HS4,HS5,HS6,HS7,HS8,HS9,IV41,IV42"
strInput = "HS24AB"
arrPostCodes = Split(strPostCode, ",")
blnFoundMatch = False
For x=0 To UBound(arrPostCodes)
    curPostCode = arrPostCodes(x)
    'If Left(strInput, Len(curPostCode))=curPostCode Then
    If InStr(strInput, curPostCode)>0 Then
        blnFoundMatch = True
        Exit For
    End If
Next
Erase arrPostCodes
If blnFoundMatch Then
    'match found, do something...
End If
```

The above will look for each post code anywhere in the user input e.g. "4AB HS2" will also return a match; if you want the post code to only appear in the beginning of the input, use the alternative `If` line that is remarked in the above code.

Comment: I went for the alternative line that is commented out, working a treat thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could split your search string into characters and then in a loop check if that character exists in the string. Sorry about the code - rusty too, but I think you can see what I'm saying...

```
Dim strPostCode As String = "HS1,HS2,HS3,HS4,HS5,HS6,HS7,HS8,HS9,IV41,IV42" 
Dim SearchString As String = "HS24AB"
Dim Match As Boolean = False

Dim i As Integer 

For(i = 0; i< SearchString.Length; i++)
  If(strPostCode.Contains(SearchString.charAt(i)) Then
    Match = True
  Else
   Match = False
  End If
Next
```